Water Damage to Wall Near Shower
A little section of drywall near my shower is water damaged. Basically, the lower edge of the drywall right next to where the shower tiles begin is brown and curled up, and the paint is a little peeled.
I can figure out how to fix it but here is my question:
The damage occurred many years ago and appears to have stabilized.  In other words, the wall has looked pretty much the same for quite some time now, ever since the original damage occured.
My common sense tells me that I should not patch the wall without first resolving the root cause. But here, I am thinking this must have been a one-time thing back when this happened. I have to think that if there were an ongoing leak, the wall would have become much worse over time.
Any experience or thoughts to offer would be very appreciated.

Please post a photo

OK there you go.

There's orange mold still on the outside of the door frame and the trim tile there.  Or has that mold also been there many years?

If this really hasn't deteriorated in years, and is now stable, the sensible thing to do, IMO, would be to patch and repaint, and hope it doesn't reoccur; It's a small job which can be done quickly, easily and cheaply. If it does come back, you've really lost nothing but time.
On the other hand, attempting to repair a leak that you really don't know the location of, is fraught with danger, and there's a good chance that you may actually make it worse, ending up being far more costly to repair properly.
